# CSS3 transition - change animation "anchor point"?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to use css3 transition to enlarge a div width and height on :hover.

It works fine but I need to change the anchor point of the animation.

As for now it is set to the bottom left of the div and I need it to be from the top left corner.

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `transform-origin` property.
This allows you to say something like:

```
transform-origin:left top;
```

You can find more information about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Hope this helps!