# How to show sub-menu in a circular navigation menu on click of an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate, traversal, jquery-traversing

This question follows on from a previous question which can be found here: [Need to fadeIn each circle 1 after the other with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351840/need-to-fadein-each-circle-1-after-the-other-with-jquery)

Basically now when the 'Climate Change and energy' circle is clicked, I need to hide all the other circles apart from the clicked circle and show a sub set or other circles that follow the same path as the original circles. But the new circles start from the next point on from the clicked circle.

I have attached a picture of what needs to be shown when you click on the circle, which can be seen here: http://cl.ly/EO95

Here is the code that I attempted it with:

HTML:

```
<div class="circle_holder seventh">
                <div class="circle pie">
                    <a href="#"><span>climate change and energy</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_circles hidden">
                    <div class="circle_holder eighth">
                        <div class="circle pie">
                            <a href="#"><span>energy efficiency</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle_holder first">
                        <div class="circle pie">
                            <a href="#"><span>renewable energy</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle_holder second">
                        <div class="circle pie">
                            <a href="#"><span>carbon finance</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="circle_holder third">
                        <div class="circle pie">
                            <a href="#"><span>climate adaptation</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div
                    <div class="circle_holder fourth">
                        <div class="circle pie">
                            <a href="#"><span>ghg footprint assessment</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.version < 9) {
    var circle = $('.circles .circle_holder > .circle');
    $(circle).animate({
        height: 168,
        width: 168,
        left: '0',
        top: '0'
    }, 1000);
    if (window.PIE) {
        $('.pie').each(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }
}

$('.circles .circle_holder > .circle').each(function(i){
    var time = 300 * (i + 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.circle').eq(i).addClass('open').animate({opacity: '1'}, i);
        $('.circle a span').animate({opacity: '1'}, 4000);
    }, time);
});

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.circle').addClass('circles_loaded');
}, 3700);

$('.circles > .circle_holder > .circle').click( function(){
    $('.inner_circles').removeClass('hidden', function() {
        console.log($('.inner_circles').parent().hide());
        $('.inner_circles').find().parent('.circle_holder').hide();

        $('.inner_circles .circle').each(function(i){
            var time = 300 * (i + 1);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.inner_circles .circle').eq(i).addClass('open').animate({opacity: '1'}, i);
                $('.inner_circles .circle a span').animate({opacity: '1'}, 4000);
            }, time);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a link to a jsFiddle containing all the HTML/CSS & JS: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasbritton/wV867/

If anyone could help me out with this I would very much appreciate it as have been tearing my hair out over this for hours.

I am on skype if anyone would like to talk through it if it might help things.

Thanks

Comment: well, I tried to create a fiddle to play with - using your 'old' (previous question) CSS but with no success...

Comment: no, I mean, we are missing some CSS in this question, and it would be great the you already provided the circles subset and other stuff you need... (P.S. i get a 'working demo' by adding the JS from this question to the answerer's demo on the other question. )

Comment: Oh ok, I have put this into a fiddle which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasbritton/wV867/

Comment: only on 'food and water' click should popup the extra circles?

Comment: On click of 'climate change and energy', the seventh circle round

Comment: Something like... http://jsbin.com/ilifej/5/edit ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to reach you on skype but you did not accepted invite.
Anyway: **click on climate change and energy**.

## [DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ilifej/5/edit)

Sorry for ruining your CSS, complete JS, ... :)

but I tought this could help. Take a look at the CSS : you don't have to setup manually the elements around the bg circle. Just try to follow the concept and redo the colors I left. Good luck!

```
var $outerC = $('.circle').not('.inner_circles > div > .circle');

var cX = 120; // center - distance from left
var cY = 130; // center - distance from top
var rad = 190; // SET .box DISTANCE (Radius from center);
var boxN = $outerC.length;

function circus(){
  $outerC.each(function(i,e){
    
      thisWc = $(e).outerWidth(true)/2;
      thisHc = $(e).outerHeight(true)/2;   
      var angle = (360/boxN)*i;
      var X = Math.round(cX+rad* Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180))-2;
      var Y = Math.round(cY+rad*-Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180))-2;  
      $(e).css({left:(X-thisWc), top:(Y-thisHc)});
    
  });
}
circus();

function fader(){
  $outerC.each(function(i,e){
          var time = 300*i;
          setTimeout(function(){
              $(e).addClass('open').animate({opacity: '1'}, time);
              $('.circle a span').animate({opacity: '1'}, 4000);
          }, time);
  });
}
fader();

$outerC.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
    $outerC.fadeTo(300,0); // hide old ones
    $outerC = $(this).next('.hidden').find('.circle');   // set new
    boxN = $outerC.length;
    
    $('.hidden').show();
    $outerC.show();
    
    fader();
    circus(); 
  
});
```

You should find another, more programmable way to 'center' your texts inside your circles.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, would you be able to help so I can reverse this so the sub circles hide and the previous circles show?

Answer (score 1):

it worth taking a look at: https://github.com/liri/moonMenuJS
it's not a full circle menu, but pretty nice.